# To Edit Confluence Page from Linux Machine

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Do we have any free tools to edit the Confluence page from linux machine ? Appreciate the response.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly by editing from Linux Machine? Are you looking to edit pages via terminal? If so - you can use Confluence `REST API` and `curl` to edit your pages:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"id":"3604482","type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":2}}' http://URL:PORT/confluence/rest/api/content/3604482 | python -mjson.tool
```

Above `curl` will edit the pages that already exist in Confluence. You can check REST API Examples [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples)

Comment: Voted up this answer. Just one note. There is a lot of ways how to update it. This one is for REST API, also you can find a lot of examples how to do that in Java or you can rewrite it to Python or whatever.... Goole -> Confluence REST API update confluence page.... Easier than asking here ;) Btw check https://answers.atlassian.com/ for everything what you want to know

Comment: Thanks @Hrabosch just as a FYI Atlassian moved the Answers to Atlassian Community as of today ;-)

Comment: Really? I am out for a long time from Atlassian community so I dont follow latest news. Thank you for information. It's not for long when they moved to their Answers system and now they are moving... again :D

Comment: @Hrabosch here is the announcement : https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/63921161/announcing-the-new-atlassian-community